# Search Multiple directories and return one result

Tags: linux, search, aix

I'm trying to bring a piece of code that I had running on an AIX box over to Linux and I just can't get it to work.

```
[ -f $FolderPath/*/FileName.txt ] && echo 1 || echo 0
```

The above searchs the FolderPath and then the * is all its subdirectories looking for FileName.txt. If it is found (more than once), it returns 1, otherwise returns 0.

In Linux, I get the Too Many Arguments error, so I thought changing to [[ ]] would fix this, but it doesn't seem to handle the wildcard * in that.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following command and then query the status code `$?`:

```
find $FolderPath -name 'FileName.txt' | grep -E '*'
```

This returns 1 when there are no files listed by the `find` command and 0 when there are.

Optionally, if you're only interested in hitting a specific level to avoid deep searches down the directory tree then you can use the `-maxdepth n` option.

Comment: Won't that stumble over the same issue, "too many arguments"?

Comment: Also it delivers more hits, since it searches recursively.

Comment: I tried this on my Linux environment and it works without error with a test directory tree similar to what you're using. Regarding the recursion, are you only interested in looking at directories one layer down?

Comment: Sorry, don't confuse me with the OP... Sure that works if there are only a few matches, but apparently the OP has a situation where too many hits occur. I made the first comment since in my eyes it creates a list of all hits which is the further processed, which _should_ result in the same issue, since it is the same situation.

Comment: This will not generate a `too many arguments` error.  Nothing in this answer generates an argument list.  The '*' in the `grep` command is matching the standard input to `grep`; it's not a shell wildcard.  That said, I think you mean `.` not `*` (because `*` in a regular expression means "the previous character, zero or more times").  Maybe just `| grep -q '.'`

Comment: Which is not an argument list to a command.  It's just a stream of data on stdin.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you were OP. Perhaps I am being naive but I'm unable to see how one can search for a file in a tree without prior indexing or hitting several directories which don't contain the file.

Comment: @LewisNorton Thanks for the suggestion, it put me on the right line. I ended up altering it slightly and its given me the right result. My final piece of code was `find $FolderPath -name 'FileName.txt' | grep -E '*' >> /dev/null && echo 0 || echo 1`